# How did the Exchange Rate Mechanism work?

Tags: exchange

The Exchange Rate Mechanism was introduced by the European Economic Community in 1979.

It fixes the Exchange rates between currencies to a specific margin.

But how does it do this?

Answer (score 1):

How the system operated changed over time.

[This Bank of England paper does a review of the literature.](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/-/media/boe/files/quarterly-bulletin/1991/the-exchange-rate-mechanism-of-the-european-monetary-system-a-review-of-the-literature) Rather than give an inaccurate summary, I will let you look through it.